# Ownership transfer

Tags: profile, administration, admin

Is there a way to ensure that a certain profile will **always** be able to change the ownership of an Opportunity without having admin privileges and/or own the parent account?

*Case:*

Profile A (user 1) tries to change ownership of an Opportunity to Profile B (user 2). Account is owned by Profile C (user 3).

Role Hierarchy user 3 > user 1 > user 2.

*Stumbles  upon this:*

> Error: The user reparenting the opportunity must be the owner of the target account, the boss of the owner, or an administrator

Clearly, I do not wish to respect this hierarchy. Both the user who tries to change the ownership and the new owner have read and write access on the account but that is probably irrelevant.
Is there a way to do this without making user 1 having unecessary privileges (Modify All Data) & without changing the Account owner to either user 1 or user 2?

Answer (score 1):

There is a permission called 'Transfer record'. You can assign that on profile or you can create a permission set with the above-mentioned permission and user to it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I've already assigned this permission on the profile that attempts to change the ownership but I still get the same error.

Comment: Error is same or different?

Comment: The error is the same.

Comment: According to the error, the problem is due to role hierarchy. The user changing the owner must have a higher role than the account owner. You can change owner from user3.

Comment: There is no other way to bypass this then, thanks!